# Array fails to populate with data in Python Jupyter using Pandas, don't know where the bug comes from

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I get the following error, which essentially means that my data failed to populate:

```
`ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 18)) while a minimum of 1 is required by PowerTransformer.
```

Tracing backwards, I find that the error comes from the following line of codes:

```
backTest = getPortTimeSeries(y_withData_Test, X_test, 
                        daily_stock_prices_data, 
                        trained_model_pipeline)
```

Which comes from the following custom function:

```
def getPortTimeSeries(y_withData, X, daily_stock_prices, 
                      ml_model_pipeline, verbose=True):
    # set date range to make stock picks over
    dr=pd.date_range(start='2009-01-01', periods=11, freq='Y') 
    # For each date in the date_range, make stock selections
    # and plot the return results of those stock selections
    port_perf_all_years = pd.DataFrame()
    perfRef=1 # performance starts at 1.
    for curr_date in dr:
        [comp, this_year_perf, ticker_list] = \
        getPortTimeSeriesForYear(curr_date, y_withData, X,\
                                 daily_stock_prices, ml_model_pipeline)
        if verbose: # If you want text output
            print("Backtest performance for year starting ",\
                  curr_date, " is:",\
                  round((this_year_perf.iloc[-1]-1)*100,2), "%")
            print("With stocks:", ticker_list)
            for tick in ticker_list:
                print(tick, "Performance was:",\
                      round((comp[tick].iloc[-1]-1)*100,2), "%" )
            print("---------------------------------------------")
        # Stitch performance for every year together
        this_year_perf = this_year_perf * perfRef
        port_perf_all_years = pd.concat([port_perf_all_years,\
                                         this_year_perf])
        perfRef = this_year_perf.iloc[-1]
    # Return portfolio performance for all years
    port_perf_all_years.columns = ["Indexed Performance"]
    return port_perf_all_years
```

Tracing back the error from the function leads to the following possibilities:

```
X = 'daily_stock_prices_data'
daily_stock_prices_data=getYRawData()
```

If we test:

```
print(X.shape)
Output: (11332, 18)
```

Therefore, the problem is not in X. Next, we test for 'thisYearMask':

```
thisYearMask = y_withData['Date'].between(\
            pd.to_datetime(date_starting) - pd.Timedelta(days=60),\
            pd.to_datetime(date_starting) + pd.Timedelta(days=60) )
```

Which is a .csv file that's populated upon checking:

```
y_withData = pd.read_csv('Annual_Stock_Price_Performance_Filtered.csv',
                        index_col=0)
```

Now I'm lost as to what the problem could be.

Comment: It might be related to the 'y_withData' DataFrame not having any samples 
within the date range specified by 'thisYearMask'. 

try checking the length of 'y_withData' after applying the date filter. make sure it contains data within the specified range.

Comment: Lets try diagnose slowly, 

First print the length of 'y_withData' after applying the date filter to 'thisYearMask'. 
this is to help us verify if theres data within the specified date range.

// print("Number of samples within date range:", len(y_withData[thisYearMask]))

2. Ensure the date format in 'y_withData' matches the format used in the date comparison. print a few rows of 'y_withData' to inspect the date format:

// print(y_withData.head())

chheck if the date format is consistent and matches the format used in the date filter. n let me know the results u get

Comment: Because 'thisYearMask' is defined within a custom function, I'll need to bring it outside of the function in order to use it:

thisYearMask = y_withData['Date'].between(\
            pd.to_datetime(date_starting) - pd.Timedelta(days=60),\
            pd.to_datetime(date_starting) + pd.Timedelta(days=60) )
print("Number of samples within date range:", len(y_withData[thisYearMask]))

Output:

Number of samples within date range: 1616

Comment: Next, test for 'y_withData':

print(y_withData.head())

Which populates:

 Ticker  Open Price       Date       Volume Ticker2  Open Price2      Date2  \
0      A       66.33 2018-12-20  235326502.6       A        84.94 2019-12-20   
1      A       83.95 2019-12-19  142379703.7       A       119.23 2020-12-18   

Volume2  
0  1.943251e+08  
1  4.664016e+08

Comment: check if 'y_withData_Test' (used in getPortTimeSeries) contains any samples. B4 calling the function, add a print statement:

Comment: It seems that it does:

print(y_withData_Test.head())
print(y_withData_Test.shape)

Output 1:
Ticker  Open Price       Date        Volume Ticker2  Open Price2  \
8015     PNW       77.03 2018-02-23  1.676105e+08     PNW        93.23   
9470    SSNT        2.92 2019-03-28  9.052292e+04    SSNT         1.88   
Ouput 2:
(1134, 8)